# UITextField leave the cursor, remove the keyboard

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, cursor

There is a text field. There is a custom keyboard block. When you click on the text field, you need the system keyboard to not appear, and the cursor appears and there was an opportunity to work with it in the text field. Is it possible to do it programmatically?

Comment: See `inputView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
textField.inputView = UIView()
```

Swift 2 and above

Comment: Everything turned out just) Thank you so much

Comment: You should assign your custom keyboard to `inputView`, not an empty view.